# Telling UI if it's a mobile device

Tags: r, shiny

[This post](https://g3rv4.com/2017/08/shiny-detect-mobile-browsers) shows how to tell server side if a mobile device is detected. What about telling UI?

## THE PROBLEM:

I have [this dashboard](https://albersonmiranda.shinyapps.io/econdashboard/) and all of it's boxes have fixed `height` argument so they line up. That `height` was set for large screens and doesn't works well for small screens. I intend to change `height` to something like `height = ifelse(itsMobile, NULL, fixed_height)`, since `NULL` fits well with mobile.

The aforementioned post allows me to detect device and use that information on server side, but I can't use input functions in UI.

Comment: Have you tried using vertical height instead of pixels?

Comment: @TTS it messes with desktop layout

Comment: One solution would be to use `renderUI` to build the UI from the server side.  You would then have knowledge of the client device and could arrange and size the UI elements accordingly.